# ¿Por qué php myadmin duplica las filas que inserto?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando crear mi primera base de datos y al insertar una fila, me la duplica. He reinstalado el XAMPP e incluso he probado en una máquina virtual pero el problema persiste. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Todo esto lo hago a través de php myadmin en localhost. Desde ahí deja crear tablas. Creo una y luego le inserto datos pero los duplica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega tu consulta por favor

Comment: phpmyadmin es un programa para conectarse a una base de datos.. sera mysql? entonces tu pregunta seria sobre mysql ;)... ahora.. habra 2 registros? estas haciendo un join? de donde salen esos datos? asi como esta, la pregunta esta incompleta...

Comment: he completado un poco la pregunta, php myadmin deja crear tablas e insertar filas en ellas. Ahí es donde al crearlas las duplica.

Comment: MeN, añande porfavor el código de la consulta

Comment: Arrelado, he añadido abajo del todo de mi pregunta la causa y solución. Gracias!

Comment: @MeN la solución no va en la pregunta, para eso dispones de la zona de respuestas, por favor edita y arregla ese detalle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que finalmente está arreglado. Cuando creaba una fila de forma gráfica, me salía otra pantalla (la de la foto) y si le das a continuar te crea otra vez la fila. Pero si sales de la pantalla, sólo te crea una. No entiendo por qué lo tienen puesto así, pero estoy empezando y alguna utilidad tendrá.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es posible cambiar ese comportamiento? No había manera de encontrar respuesta a esto, gracias por poner la solución